# Using a For/Each Loop but Jumping Active Cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

So I am trying to write a For Each loop to look through an entire row. If it finds the word "Specialty" Copy it over to the next three cells. 
It does this part fine, but then when it loops around, of course the next cell has "Specialty" in it bc it just copied it over. I need to figure out how to say, if you've found "Specialty" and copied it over, jump 4 cells over and begin searching  again..... Tried Offsetting the active cell but didn't work. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

```
Sub CopySpecialtyOver()

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set rngRow = Range("A8:BA8")

For Each Cell In rngRow
    If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Specialty") Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
    Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Cell.Value
    Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell.Value

    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You could transform it into a normal `for` loop and go from right to left instead of left to right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to loop backwards given your current code:

```
Sub CopySpecialtyOver()

    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim cIndex As Long

    Set rngRow = Range("A8:BA8")

    For cIndex = rngRow.Columns.Count To rngRow.Column Step -1
        Set Cell = Cells(rngRow.Row, cIndex)
        If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Specialty", vbTextCompare) Then
            Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next cIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up solving it with what I posted below

Answer (score 0):

You could replace 'For each' by a an integer iterable:

```
Sub CopySpecialtyOver()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set rngRow = Range("A8:BA8")

    For i = 1 To rngRow.Cells.Count
        Set Cell = rngRow(1, i)
        If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Specialty") Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Cell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell.Value
            i = i + 3
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! I ended up solving it like this:

```
Sub CopySpecialtyOver()

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set rngRow = Range("A8:BA8")

For Each Cell In rngRow
If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Specialty") Then
    If InStr(1, Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, "Specialty") Then
    Else
       Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
       Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Cell.Value
       Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell.Value
       End If
End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Emty `If` branches are not a very nice style ... why not just negate the `If` condition and dum the `Else`?

Comment: and on a 2nd look I don't seem to trust this logic 100% ... what happens if the 4th column after a "Specialty" contains  the search term again?

Answer (score 0):

`For Each` - as pointed out by other responses - may not be the best strategy. Nevertheless - as you asked for it - here comes a piece of code using some in-loop control to overcome the deficites of `For Each` in this use case:

```
Sub CopySpecialtyOver()

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim Cnt As Integer

Set rngRow = Range("A8:BA8")
Found = False
Cnt = 0

For Each Cell In rngRow.Cells

    If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Specialty") And Not Found Then
        ' capture start of sequence - otherwise do nothing
        Found = True
        Cnt = 0
    Else

        If Found Then
            'if in Found mode increment counter
            Cnt = Cnt + 1

            ' expand using negative offset
            If Cnt <= 3 Then
                Cell = Cell.Offset(0, -Cnt).Value
            End If

            ' break after 3rd
            If Cnt = 3 Then
                Found = False
                Cnt = 0
            End If

        End If

    End If

Next Cell
End Sub
```

This seemingly more complex code will have its advantage when run vertically (instead horizontally) over much more than just a handfull of cells, as `For/Each` performs much better than regular `For/Next`